# How can we retrieve same data in one table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need one very expert help, I can't seem to find the answer to this, the problem is, find the titles and ISBNs of books that have the same title and publishers as at least 2 other books.

Order it by title.

So basically, everything is coming from the book table.

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK 
(
   ISBN VARCHAR2(20),
   Title VARCHAR2(250) NOT NULL,
   YearPublished NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
   PublisherName VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT pk_isbnP PRIMARY KEY(ISBN)
);
```

Here is my rough draft:

```
select _____
from book b2
where ______ (select____ from book b2
             where _____ = ______ and ______ =______)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
select isbn, title
from books
where (title,publishername) in(select title,publishername 
                                 from books
                                 group by title,publishername
                                 having count(*) >=3)
order by title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Find combinations of title and publisher that have at least 2 books:

```
SELECT title, PublisherName 
FROM BOOK
GROUP BY title, PublisherName 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Step 2:  find all other books that have this title and publisher:

```
SELECT *
FROM Books b1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT title, PublisherName 
    FROM BOOK b2
    WHERE b1.title = b2.title AND b1.PublisherName = b2.PublisherName 
    GROUP BY title, PublisherName 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: I see the logic, but the required output is still not appearing. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select b1.title, b1.isbn 
from book b1 
inner join 
  (select title, publishername 
   from book
   group by title, publishername having count(*) > 2) b2 
on b1.title = b2.title and b1.publishername = b2.publishername
order by b1.title
```

The inner query fetches the titles/publishers of books where there are three or more duplicates. The outer query uses those results to get the associated ISBNs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by statement here.

```
SELECT title
      ,isbn
  FROM BOOKS
  group by title, isbn
  having COUNT(1) >= 2 order by title;
```

Comment: `[title]` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the query in sql server management studio with sample data. In question database used is not mentioned.
As per msdn in Transact-SQL title is not a keyword.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: `title` is a valid identifier. `[title]` isn't

Comment: This question is tagged Oracle.

Comment: Ok, i think the issue was with the presence of square brackets '[]', which are automatically added in the Sql Server Management Studio. 
Updated the answer by removing the brackets. Hope it's fine now :)

I don't have access to Oracle Data Base but all the keywords now used are standard sqls.

[] is a grouping character in oracle, as per the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm